# What does it mean by piecewise smooth boundary?

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus

I will be highly obliged if anyone can give me any reference where i can get the definition of domain (in $\mathbb{R^n}$) with piecewise smooth boundary.

My question is when a domain in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is said to have a piecewise smooth boundary?

I tried a lot to find in Google but i didn't get.Please help me out.

Comment: My guess would be that the boundary of the domain is a union of $(n-1)$-dimensional smooth manifolds.

Comment: @Tunococ you mean union of $n-1$ dimensional smooth manifold with boundary or without boundary.If it is without boundary then there is a problem as boundary can't be written as union of open set.If it is with boundary what conditions are on the boundary?

Comment: I believe it's supposed to be smooth manifolds with boundary. I am not sure what you mean by conditions on the boundary. If I may guess, the charts that intersect the boundary must map smoothly to the closed half-plane.

Comment: @ Tunococ So is it true that for a corner(extreme) point of a closed square square there exist a chart that maps smoothly onto  the closed half plane?

Comment: The boundary of a square is one-dimensional. It is a union of four smooth $1$-manifolds with boundary. One corner is included in two of the four pieces.

Comment: @Tunococ then What about cube? Boundary of cube is not union of smooth manifold.

Comment: Mmm... If a cube is supposed to have piecewise smooth boundary, the definition definitely has to change. Maybe it is a manifold whose boundary is the closure of a union of smooth manifolds?

Answer (score 3):

I do not think there is a commonly agreed on definition. Here is one, based on the discussion in

William Thurston, Three-dimensional geometry and topology. Vol. 1. Edited by Silvio Levy. Princeton Mathematical Series, 35. Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ, 1997.

A  domain $\Omega$ in $R^n$ has piecewise smooth boundary if for each $x\in cl(\Omega)$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $R^n$ and a diffeomorphism $f: U\to U'\subset R^n$, such that $f(cl(\Omega))\cap U$ equals $\Omega'\cap U'$, where $\Omega'\subset R^n$ is a convex polyhedron.

Answer (score -2):

I got stuck on the definition of piecewise smooth boundary while reviewing material for a calculus course I am taking. I can't intuitively see the what the definition means but it happens to solve your question.

The definition is: if the **boundary** of a set is a **finite union** of **piecewise**, **simple closed curves**, then the set has a piecewise smooth boundary and moreover, the set itself called **regular region**.

My own interpretation is that if every collection of curves which forms the boundary of such a set does not self-intersect in any way, then the boundary formed from those curves is said to be piecewise smooth boundary.

Comment: The definition you provide only works in $\Bbb R^2$, and moreover is wrong - we need to assume these curves are smooth, which means that they have a $C^1$ parametrization for which the derivative never vanishes.